# Python replace tuples from list of tuples by highest priority list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have those python lists :

```
x = [('D', 'F'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B')]
priority_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G'] # Ordered from highest to lowest priority
```

How can I, for each tuple in my list, keep the value with the highest priority according to `priority_list`? The result would be :

```
['D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Another examples:

```
x = [('B', 'D'), ('E', 'A'), ('B', 'A'), ('D', 'F'), ('E', 'C')]
priority_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
# Result:
['B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'C']

x = [('B', 'C'), ('F', 'E'), ('B', 'A'), ('D', 'F'), ('E', 'C')]
priority_list = ['F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'] # Notice the change in priorities
# Result:
['C', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'E']
```

Thanks in advance, I might be over complicating this.

Comment: clarify your logic, how the expected result is composed?

Comment: Looks like you’re just taking the first value from each tuple in that case map and operator.itemgetter would work or a very simple list comprehension

Comment: the sample data is misleading. We don't even need `priority_list` here. Just take the first element of each tuple... it's already attracting a lot of answers but we don't know the real test cases

Comment: @Waroulolz: what would be the output for `x = [('D', 'F'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'A')]`? Could you add more tuples so it becomes clearer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
[sorted(i, key=priority_list.index)[0] for i in x]
```

though it will throw an exception if you find a value not in the priority list.

Comment: `sorted(…, key=…)[0]` may be replaced with `min(…, key=…)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
def get_priority_val(data, priority_list):
    for single_val in priority_list:
        if single_val in data:
            return single_val


x = [('D', 'F'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B')]
priority_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G']
final_data = []

for data in x:
    final_data.append(get_priority_val(data, priority_list))

print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
['D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using list comprehension:

```
ans = [d[0]  if priority_list.index(d[0]) < priority_list.index(d[1] )  else d[1] for d in x ]
```

output:

```
['D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line using a list comprehension :

```
[y[0] if priority_list.index(y[0]) < priority_list.index(y[1]) else y[1] for y in x]
```

---

Output :

```
['D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict containing priority values and just use `min` with a custom key

```
>>> priority_dict = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(priority_list)}
>>> [min(t, key=priority_dict.get) for t in x]
['D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```